# SVN: checkout from multiple URLs to the current working directory under same path?

Tags: svn

We have a repository named "nagios" with the following paths under it:

```
common/nagios/etc
common/nagios/objects

FTW/nagios/etc
FTW/nagios/etc/objects

DAL/nagios/etc
DAL/nagios/etc/objects
```

As you can see the directory structures below "common", "DAL" and "FTW" are identitical.

I'd like to be able to checkout (not export) the "common" paths first, e.g. (cd /usr/local):

```
svn co http://foobar/repo/nagios/common/nagios nagios
```

Then, depending on which client site (server) I'm on, checkout that site's specific files, e.g.:

```
svn co http://foobar/repo/nagios/FTW/nagios nagios
```

Which gives me the error:
**svn: 'nagios' is already a working copy for a different URL**

Note: there are no identical/overlapping files between "commmon" and "FTW" (or "DAL")

I've tried to accomplish this several ways including using "svn:externals" (which gets me close, but creates a new directory structure under the existing one - ../nagios/nagios/etc/...).

The object here is to maintain all of the files that are common to each site in a single location and the site specific files in each of their own directories in the repo and be able to checkout the common ones and the site specific ones to the same working directory paths.

Answer (score 2):

You **can get needed result**, *while* and *if*

- COMMON and HOST files are stored in the same repository
- You use SVN 1.6 or later (I'll recommend to start using 1.8)

Solution is **file-based externals**: re-read carefully ["Externals Definitions" in SVN-Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html), starting from words

> Subversion 1.6 also introduced support for external definitions for files. File externals are configured just like externals for directories and appear as a versioned file in the working copy.

I.e you **files** in `common/nagios/etc` + `common/nagios/objects` will be maintained files, files inside HOST-tree - externals to files in COMMON (if all files have unique names). Checkouted HOST-tree will have all files in Working Copy (if externals wasn't disabled on checkout)

Comment: That worked perfectly (once I realized I was running 1.5.7 and upgraded :-)!  The only minor problem I have now is that if I run `svn list -R --include-externals` I do not see the externals, but that's no real issue.

Thanks!